# Deploying flows through CumulusCI

Tags: visual-workflow, cumulusci

I have a full Salesforce repository in Vs Code that I deployed with the command `cci task run deploy`. I had some issues including a recent change of mine which included a new Quick Action that runs a new Flow.
After removing my latest changes I was able to deploy the full repository with the command

```
cci task run deploy --org myOrg --unmanaged true  --path .\force-app\main\default\
```

Ater that I decided to add again and deploy first my flow. I'm trying the same command but this time I'm limiting it using the `--path` option to only include the flows and flowdefinitions folders like this

```
cci task run deploy --org myOrg --unmanaged true  --path .\force-app\main\default\flows\
cci task run deploy --org myOrg --unmanaged true  --path .\force-app\main\default\flowDefinitions\
```

Even when both commands end with Success, my new flow is not deployed to my org. Everything else that I deployed with my first command is there without issue.

Am I missing something specific to deploying flows with Cumulus CI? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a little in the Project, the cause was that both folders were added to the `.forceignore` file

[image]

What caught my attention about that was that the cci commands for the flow folders always included the message: `Payload size: 316 bytes`. It seemed strange to me because I think it was too small of a size for any metadata file so I decided to check ignored files in the project and found the cause.

Comment: Under the hood, CumulusCI asks `sf` or `sfdx` to convert your source-format metadata to deployable Metadata API format. `sf` applies the `.forceignore` file transparently where appropriate. (I am on the CumulusCI team).

Comment: Thanks!! I saw the documentation of other commands like dx_push so I suspected that. It helped me to solve this issue